# TypeShape and dynamic generics

Tags: generics, casting, f#

I'm trying to use [TypeSharp](https://github.com/eiriktsarpalis/TypeShape).
So far, I only had to use `shapeof<'T>` in a following manner:

```
type AwsConfig = {
    AccessKeyId : string
    DefaultRegion : string
    SecretAccessKey : string
  }


let targetTypeShape = shapeof<AwsConfig> //targetTypeShape is of type targetTypeShape<AwsConfig>
match targetTypeShape with
| Shape.FSharpRecord (:? ShapeFSharpRecord<AwsConfig> as shape) -> foo shape   
// 'shape' is of type ShapeFSharpRecord<AwsConfig>, which is important //             
| _ -> failwith "some other cases"
```

But now I'd like to create  dynamically `shapeof` like

```
let awsConfigInstance = {AccessKeyId="123";DefaultRegion="asd";SecretAccessKey="asddd"}
let awsType = awsConfigInstance.GetType()
let targetTypeShape = shapeof<awsType> //that doesn't compile obviously
```

So i though i could do something like this

```
let typeShape = TypeShape.Create (awsConfigInstance.GetType())
match typeShape with
//'shape' is of type IShapeFSharpRecord not ShapeFSharpRecord<AwsConfig> as i need it too be
| Shape.FSharpRecord shape->                                
                      let castedShape = shape :?> ShapeFSharpRecord<_> //error
                      foo castedShape
```

the error on line `shape :?> ShapeFSharpRecord<_>` is as follows:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 
'ShapeFSharpRecord`1[FsConfig.Tests.Common+AwsConfig]' to type 
'ShapeFSharpRecord`1[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[FsConfig.Tests.Common+AwsConfig]]'.'
```

I also tried to this trick:

```
let typeShape = TypeShape.Create (awsConfigInstance.GetType())
match typeShape with
//'shape' is of type IShapeFSharpRecord not ShapeFSharpRecord<AwsConfig> as i need it too be
| Shape.FSharpRecord shape-> 
                      let temp = Activator.CreateInstanceGeneric<ShapeFSharpRecord<_>>([|typeShape .Type|], [||])
                      let castedShape = temp :?> ShapeFSharpRecord<_> //error
                      foo castedShape
```

Error is on line `let castedShape = temp :?> ShapeFSharpRecord<_>`

```
'Unable to cast object of type 'ShapeFSharpRecord`1[FsConfig.Tests.Common+AwsConfig]' 
to type 'ShapeFSharpRecord`1[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[FsConfig.Tests.Common+AwsConfig]]'.'
```

I have no clue where is  `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption` coming from.
Any ideas how could i dynamically create ShapeFSharpRecord instance?

Comment: There is only one place option could be coming from: the type of `foo`. You didn't show the code for `foo`, but resulting error message definitely indicates that `foo` expects a parameter of type `ShapeFSharpRecord<AwsConfig option>`

Comment: True! I mean, the `foo` actually expects `ShapeFSharpRecord<AwsConfig>` but when i remove `foo shape` line i get error ```'Unable to cast object of type 'ShapeFSharpRecord`1[FsConfig.Tests.Common+AwsConfig]' to type 'ShapeFSharpRecord`1[System.Object]'.'
```

Comment: `foo` definitely doesn't expect what you say it expects. It definitely expects a type involving `option`. If you show the code for `foo`, perhaps I'd be able to point that out more precisely. If you remove the call to `foo`, then in the absence of any basis for inferring the target type, the compiler falls back to `Object`.

Comment: Bartek's point is that `foo` is irrelevant and can be removed entirely. The problem is that the dynamic version of the code (`TypeShape.Create`) fails, while the static version (`shapeof<AwsConfig>`) succeeds.

Comment: Thats true brianberns, but now I'm also intrigued by Fyodors points :D

Comment: Dynamic version fails for the exact same reason: target type has the option.

Comment: Just try `shape :?> ShapeFSharpRecord<AwsConfig>`. You'll get a compile-time error calling `foo`, but the cast itself will work. Remove the `foo` call to verify.

Comment: I actually simplified the code for this post, but I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about TypeShape, but I've just looked at its source code a bit and reproduced what you're seeing. Unfortunately, I think the short answer is just "you can't do that".

To be more specific, if you want access to the underlying shape of an `FSharpRecord`, then you have to know its type at compile time. If you try to finesse it by casting to `ShapeFSharpRecord<_>`, the compiler isn't able to infer the type and uses `obj` (i.e. `System.Object`) instead.

So, the actual type of the shape is `ShapeFSharpRecord<AwsConfig>`, but you're trying to cast it to a `ShapeFSharpRecord<obj>`, which can't be done and results in a runtime exception.

(I'm ignoring issues related to the signature of the `foo` function, which I don't think are central to your question.)

Comment: for now I'll simply refuse failure :) as long as i'm trying to learn more about @fyodor's point but once i'm done i'll consider concede